# When I load data within a function how can I get it into the calling environment

Tags: r, function, local, environment

Probably a simple question (I hope). I have a function like the one below. Depending on the parameters it will construct the name of the Rdata file as character. It will then load that file. It can also create the name of the single object in that file.

How do I get the object into the calling environment?

```
fn=function(pars){

   file.name # created from pars

   load(file="file.name")

   object.name # also created from pars object of that name will not be in local environment

   NULL # How do I get the object into the main environment after this call?
}
```

Comment: The [`?load`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/load.html) docs do mention `envir=`, and demos its use with `envir=.GlobalEnv` in the example code.

Answer (score 1):

You may `load` the data directly in global environment.

```
fn=function(pars){
  file.name # created from pars
  load(file="file.name", envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: How about if I wrapped fn inside another function and want the object to be available in the outer function? I note that the default envir is parent.frame() and this is what I originally assumed it meant, but clearly it doesn't. I looked at the documentation for sys.parent and it is pretty confusing. Thanks again in advance.

Comment: You *do* want `parent.frame()` there.  The default refers to the parent from the point of view of `load()`.  If you specify it, it will be the parent from the point of view of `fn`.   Default parameter values are evaluated in the frame of the function being called, explicit parameter values are evaluated in the caller frame.

Comment: That works as hoped so my problem is solved. However, I clearly had some roadblock in my thinking. Your explanation about defaults and explicit parameters being evaluated in different frame is just what I needed. Many thanks again.